# Returning data to a view which has a model which references other models

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

So I have my model

```
public class AgencyAll
{
    public Agency Agency { get; set; }
    public AgencySector AgencySector { get; set; }
    public AgencyExpertise AgencyExpertise { get; set; }
}
```

which acts a reference to other models so I can pass these into my view

Example - Agency model

```
public partial class Agency
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int createdby { get; set; }
    public string createdbytype { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime lastupdated { get; set; }
    public int lastupdatedby { get; set; }
    public string lastupdatedbytype { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

The AgencySector and AgencyExpertise are only contain the agency id and the other id (sector or expertise) as it's a many to many relationship

Part of my view

```
@model AgencyAll
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        Sector:
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgencySector.sectorid, (SelectList) ViewBag.SectorList, new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        Specialisation:
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgencyExpertise.expertiseid, (SelectList) ViewBag.SpecialismList, new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I can call the different models fine

My problem occurs here

```
public ActionResult ViewData(int id)
{
    ViewBag.CountyList = new SelectList(GetCountyList(), "Value", "Text");
    ViewBag.SectorList = new SelectList(GetSectorList(), "Value", "Text");
    ViewBag.SpecialismList = new SelectList(GetSpecialisationList(), "Value", "Text");

    return View(_db.Agencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));
}
```

specifically, this line; `return View(_db.Agencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));`

I am trying to return the agency data for the url ViewData/(id) however as the model for the view is AgencyAll, it cannot assign the dataset to the model as the model does not refer to a table, it refers to multiple models which refer to tables. The return statement is expecting the view to have the Agency model, not AgencyAll.

I cannot figure out what I need to replace `return View(_db.Agencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));` with in order to pass the data from the class to the model which has the model of the table, to show the data,

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just asking how to create an instance of an object?  Like this?:  `return View(new AgencyAll { Agency = _db.Agencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id) });`

Comment: Wow...and thanks, I think I'm just having an off day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be providing the expected model to your view, which is *AgencyAll*. At the moment you're providing an *Agency* object.

Change your code to something like this:

```
    public ActionResult ViewData(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.CountyList = new SelectList(GetCountyList(), "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.SectorList = new SelectList(GetSectorList(), "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.SpecialismList = new SelectList(GetSpecialisationList(), "Value", "Text");

        var viewModel = new AgencyAll {
            Agency = _db.Agencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id),
            AgencySector = _db.AgencySectors.FirstOrDefault(),
            AgencyExpertise = _db.AgencyExpertises.FirstOrDefatul()
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```